Code runs succesfully but getting "Bad File Descriptor" errors when using python3 + asyncio
The following code runs successfully (I can print the results of the main function), but on shutdown I get a bunch of exceptions:
from pathlib import Path
import asyncio
from tqdm.asyncio import tqdm_asyncio
from lib import get_gcs_fs, run, get_gcs_folder

async def check_sentinel_exists(cloud_fs, sample_id, sentinel):
    exists = await cloud_fs._exists(sentinel)
    return sample_id if exists else None

async def filter_samples(cloud_fs, sample_id_with_sentinel):
    tasks = [check_sentinel_exists(cloud_fs, sample_id, sentinel) 
             for sample_id, sentinel in sample_id_with_sentinel]
    results = await tqdm_asyncio.gather(*tasks, desc="Checking files")
    return list(filter(None, results))

async def main():
    cloud_fs = get_gcs_fs()

    GCS_TSV = "..."
    GCS_PREFIX = "..."

    # Download TSV file if not exists
    if not Path("/tmp/rows.tsv").exists():
        run(f"gcloud storage cp {GCS_TSV} /tmp/rows.tsv")

    # Prepare sample_id_with_sentinel list
    sample_id_with_sentinel = []
    for line in Path("/tmp/rows.tsv").read_text().splitlines():
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        sample_id, _ = line.split("\t")
        WORK_SENTINEL = f"{get_gcs_folder(GCS_PREFIX, sample_id)}/stages/SOME_STAGE.DONE"
        sample_id_with_sentinel.append((sample_id, WORK_SENTINEL))

    filtered_sample_ids = await filter_samples(cloud_fs, sample_id_with_sentinel)
    return filtered_sample_ids

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sample_ids = asyncio.run(main())
    print(sample_ids)

Exceptions:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 684, in _process_write_backlog
    self._transport.write(chunk)
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 924, in write
    self._fatal_error(exc, 'Fatal write error on socket transport')
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 719, in _fatal_error
    self._force_close(exc)
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 731, in _force_close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, exc)
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Fatal error on SSL transport
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7f7a32eca5c0>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport closing fd=25>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 918, in write
    n = self._sock.send(data)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 684, in _process_write_backlog
    self._transport.write(chunk)
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 924, in write
    self._fatal_error(exc, 'Fatal write error on socket transport')
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 719, in _fatal_error
    self._force_close(exc)
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 731, in _force_close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, exc)
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Fatal error on SSL transport
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7f7a32eca770>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport closing fd=29>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ved/micromamba/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 918, in write
    n = self._sock.send(data)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Given that the code is completing, I'm not sure what the issue is. Any thoughts?
The error is happening on exit because adding an asyncio.sleep(10) delays the exception till shutdown.

Feels like title is a bit misleading, why don't we title it like "Bad File Descripter" error  when exiting asyncio code - and also, what is lib module?

I think you need to end your main() function by closing the file system:
...
cloud_fs.close()

as documented here https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/guide.html#closing.
The specific error:
self._sock.send(data)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

is likely caused by Python trying to flush a buffered write to a socket that has already been closed when the program exits but I may well be wrong. man 7 socket is one place to start if you're interested in how Unix sockets work.
